# Changing text color of certain element on page using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So Im trying to change the color of "Instructor Notes" on a udacity.com page. You can choose any course on udacity for this purpose,youll have to login to see the instructor notes section though.

```
//Selecting the text
    var txt=d3.selectAll("div.col-xs-9.ng-scope").select("h2")
    txt.text()
    "Instructor Notes"

d3.selectAll("div.col-xs-9.ng-scope").select("h2").html()
"Instructor Notes"

// CHANGING COLOR OF THE "Instructor Notes"
txt.attr("fill","red")
[Array[1]]

txt.attr("font-color","white")
txt.attr("color","red")
```

But the color doesnt show up, even though I can see red,red,white etc in the attributes in the chrome-dev-tools elements, but none of them are getting processed.

```
<h2 fill="red" color="red" font-color="white">Instructor Notes</h2>
```

Comment: Try `.style()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff first thing is that when does one know to use .style OR .attr? Do we have to make trial and errors? Secondly its not working I tested. Just returns this -- Array[1] 0: h2 length: 1 parentNode: html.ng-scope__proto__: Array[0]....

Comment: @LarsKotthoff its not working ,please help Im confused and have tried all sort of commands,with none working

Comment: `.style()` sets style attributes, so you should use that to overwrite anything set in CSS styles. Try using `var txt = d3.select("div.col-xs-9.ng-scope > h2")`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff one last question. How did you even know that you had to "override CSS" ? How does one know when to use .style and not the .attr ?

Comment: If it's defined in CSS, you need to use `.style()`, otherwise `.attr()` will work as well. In general, use `.style()` for anything you'd set in a CSS file, like colors, fills, etc.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks but what Im asking is "How did you even know that you had to use .style() instead of .attr() ??". How do I know from looking at a d3-code if its attributes have been defined in CSS or not ?

Comment: You don't. The fact that `.attr()` *wasn't* working for you was a strong hint however.